# MySQL Database in Phpmyadmin won't update and shows no Error

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to create an Edit option in the table showing the database on my website.
The problem is even when I click Save, the database is not updated.
There are no errors showing.
There's an EditComplaint.php, which fetches data from DB and shows it in input boxes so it can be edited and Ecomp.php, which is called on clicking Save.

```
<?php

        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
        $db_user = 'Username'; // Username
        $db_pass = 'Username'; // Password
        $db_name = 'Database'; // Database Name

        $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
        if (!$conn) {
            die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
        }

        $sql = "SELECT `id`, `ref_no`, `type`, `comp_name`, `comp_no`, `station`, `pertains`, `user_remarks`, `to_whom`, `concern`, `brief_fct`, `sec_remarks`, `depart`, `cisf_remarks`, `generalcomment`, `status` FROM `Complaintstable` WHERE `Complaintstable`.`id` = '$id'";

        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (!$query) {
            die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
        }

?>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web|Roboto+Condensed:400,300|Pathway+Gothic+One|ABeeZee:400,400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="master-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="custom-stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="complaintstable.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="dmrc-favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>DMRC/Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="Ecomp.php" id="form1" method="post" name="form1">
        <!-- header section -->
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-inner">
                <div class="header-top">
                    <div class="welcome-guest">
                        <span class="align-right float-right" id="lblusername" style="color:Black;">Guest</span><em><span class="welcome-cont float-right fontfamily_2" id="lblwelcome" style="padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;color:black;">Welcome</span></em>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header-top-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="" id="active">Home</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="header-bottom">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="container clearfix">
                <br><br>
            <table class="data-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Referral/No.</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                        <th>Complainant Name</th>
                        <th>Station</th>
                        <th>Pertains To</th>
                        <th>User Remarks</th>
                        <th>To Whom</th>
                        <th>Concern</th>
                        <th>Brief Fact</th>
                        <th>Security Comments</th>
                        <th>Deptt</th>
                        <th>CISF Comments</th>
                        <th>General Comment</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $i = 0;
                        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
                        {
                            $id = $row['id'];
                            $ref_no = $row['ref_no'];
                            $type = $row['type'];
                            $comp_name = $row['comp_name'];
                            $station = $row['station'];
                            $pertains = $row['pertains'];
                            $user_remarks = $row['user_remarks'];
                            $to_whom = $row['to_whom'];
                            $concern = $row['concern'];
                            $brief_fct = $row['brief_fct'];
                            $sec_remarks = $row['sec_remarks'];
                            $depart = $row['depart'];
                            $cisf_remarks = $row['cisf_remarks'];
                            $generalcomment = $row['generalcomment'];
                            $status = $row['status'];
                            if ($i == 0)
                            {
                                $i++;
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='id' value='$id'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='ref_no' value='$ref_no'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='type' value='$type'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='comp_name' value='$comp_name'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='station' value='$station'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='pertains' value='$pertains'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='user_remarks' value='$user_remarks'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='to_whom' value='$to_whom'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='concern' value='$concern'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='brief_fct' value='$brief_fct'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='sec_remarks' value='$sec_remarks'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='depart' value='$depart'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='cisf_remarks' value='$cisf_remarks'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='generalcomment' value='$generalcomment'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><input type='text' name='status' value='$status'/></td>";
                                echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=$id' class='button-new'>Delete</a></td>";
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            echo '<br><br>';
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" class="button-new" value="Save"/>
        </div>


<div class="footer">
            <div class="footer-top">
                <div class="footer-top-inner">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">FAQs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Contact Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Disclaimer</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-bottom fontfamily_2">
                <div class="footer-bottom-inner">
                    <div class="float-left footer-text">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And Here's the Ecomp.php that Save calls

```
<?php
        $db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
        $db_user = 'Username'; // Username
        $db_pass = 'Username'; // Password
        $db_name = 'Database'; // Database Name
        // Create connection
        $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Unable to Connect to '$dname'");
        // Check connection
        if (!$con)
        {
            echo "Please try later.";
        }
        else
        {
            mysqli_select_db($con, $dname);
        }

            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $ref_no = $_POST['ref_no'];
            $type = $_POST['type'];
            $comp_name = $_POST['comp_name'];
            $station = $_POST['station'];
            $pertains = $_POST['pertains'];
            $user_remarks = $_POST['user_remarks'];
            $to_whom = $_POST['to_whom'];
            $concern = $_POST['concern'];
            $brief_fct = $_POST['brief_fct'];
            $sec_remarks = $_POST['sec_remarks'];
            $depart = $_POST['depart'];
            $cisf_remarks = $_POST['cisf_remarks'];
            $generalcomment = $_POST['generalcomment'];
            $status = $_POST['status'];

                mysqli_query($con," UPDATE `Complaintstable` SET `ref_no`= '$ref_no',`type`='$type',`comp_name`=`$comp_name`,`station`='$station',`pertains`='$pertains',`user_remarks`='$user_remarks',`to_whom`='$to_whom',`concern`='$concern',`brief_fct`='$brief_fct',`sec_remarks`='$sec_remarks',`depart`='$depart',`cisf_remarks`='$cisf_remarks',`generalcomment`='$generalcomment',`status`='$status' WHERE `Complaintstable`.`id` = '$id'");

                header("Location: complaintstable.php");

?>
```

Kindly guide me please.
Its my first time here.
Thanks in Advance.
Edit: The Update SQL query works when ran in phpmyadmin console.

Comment: FYI. PHPMyAdmin is not a database. It's simply a web based application where you can _manage_ MySQL-databases.

Comment: Okay Sir thanks for the clarification. I'll change the title.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! This also means that if any field contains the `'` characted or ends with a backslash, the query will fail.

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($con)` to your query so you can see the error.

  `mysqli_query($con,"YOUR UPDATE QUERY") or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: Also, check the servers error log and see if there's any errors in there, which there probably are.

Comment: Oh thanks for this knowledge, but this is a little project and does not have any vulnerable data that needs to be protected, its all just assumed data.

Comment: Okay gonna change it to`or die(mysqli_error($con)` and will check log.

Comment: There's _never_ any reason not to think about security. You will copy/paste parts of old code and forget to fix it. Learn properly from the start instead. Plus, as I mentioned before: _"This also means that if any field contains the ' characted or ends with a backslash, the query will fail."_ so it's not all about security.

Comment: Thank you I understand that I must always take security into consideration. None of the query ends with backslash but im not able to understand this _' charactered_ thing. Im using single quotes inside double quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i can see is that you are wrapping one of your db values `$comp_name` in backticks ` but it is probably a string..

In this line look at the $comp_name:

```
mysqli_query($con," UPDATE `Complaintstable` SET `ref_no`= '$ref_no',`type`='$type',`comp_name`='$comp_name',`station`='$station',`pertains`='$pertains',`user_remarks`='$user_remarks',`to_whom`='$to_whom',`concern`='$concern',`brief_fct`='$brief_fct',`sec_remarks`='$sec_remarks',`depart`='$depart',`cisf_remarks`='$cisf_remarks',`generalcomment`='$generalcomment',`status`='$status' WHERE `Complaintstable`.`id` = '$id'");
```

I agree with Magnus. Here is how you *could do the same with PDO*. Although prepared statements are possible in mysql too, i would always go for PDO. [See this reference](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/mysqli_comparison) if you want to spend time with it.

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=someDatabase', 'someUser', 'somePass');
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `Complaintstable` SET `ref_no`= ?,`type`=  ?,`comp_name`=?,`station`= ?,`pertains`= ?,`user_remarks`=?,`to_whom`= ?,`concern`= ?,`brief_fct`= ?,`sec_remarks`= ?,`depart`= ?,`cisf_remarks`= ?,`generalcomment`= ?,`status`= ? WHERE `Complaintstable`.`id` = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($ref_no,$type,$comp_name,$station,$pertains,$user_remarks,$to_whom,$concern,$brief_fct,$sec_remarks,$depart,$cisf_remarks,$generalcomment,$status,$id));
```

Comment: Ok sure I'll try the PDO method.@yolo

Comment: Prepared statements works just as well with mysqli, though, so you don't have to use PDO.

Comment: Thats why i said could not should :) But i adapted my answer to point that out.

Comment: I just checked in my code, you were right sir. It Worked! Thank you so much! @Yolo